# In FF old socket reconnects on longer refresh

Tags: firefox, sails.js, socket.io-1.0

the problem is that I have Socket.IO app and in FireFox on page refresh what happens is socket disconnects and tries to reconnect. If reload is long enough socket reconnects but gets disconnected anyway and new connection is created. Its really weird. There is console log output after refresh:

```
"====================================" sails.io.js:141:1
"Socket was disconnected from Sails." sails.io.js:141:1
"Usually, this is due to one of the following reasons:
 -> the server https://astrocrm.local:8082 was taken down
 -> your browser lost internet connectivity" sails.io.js:141:1
"====================================" sails.io.js:141:1
"
        Socket is trying to reconnect to Sails...
_-|>_-  (attempt #1)

" sails.io.js:141:1
"
  |>    Socket reconnected successfully after
\___/   being offline for ~1.028 seconds.

"

  |>    Now connected to Sails.
\___/   For help, see: http://bit.ly/1DmTvgK
        (using browser SDK @v0.11.0)

  |>    Now connected to Sails.
\___/   For help, see: http://bit.ly/1DmTvgK
        (using browser SDK @v0.11.0)
```

Im using Socket.IO 1.2.1 and FF 39.0 64bit Linux edition. Is this normal for FF?? Didnt notice such behaviour in Chrome.